# Khalil-like book on discrete-time nonlinear systems

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-dynamics, discrete-time

Is there an equivalent of the Khalil's [Nonlinear Systems](https://www.egr.msu.edu/%7Ekhalil/NonlinearSystems) for discrete-time systems?

I am particularly interested in matters of advanced stability analysis, perturbed systems, singular perturbation theory.

Comment: Forced or unforced?

Comment: preferably both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been looking for a discrete-time version of Khalil's Nonlinear Systems book but haven't been able to find anything. The closest thing I could find to cover the topics of Khalil is using these three references:

"Lyapunov Theory for Discrete Time Systems", https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.05289.pdf
This is a report that contains Lyapunov stability results.

"Nonlinear Dynamical Systems and Control: A Lyapunov-Based Approach" by Wassim M. Haddad, and VijaySekhar Chellaboina.
Chapter 13 has Lyapunov stability and Dissipativity results.
Chapter 14 has optimal nonlinear control.

"Stochastic Approximation, A Dynamic Systems Viewpoint" by Vivek Borkar.
If you ignore the stochastic elements, the book relates a discrete-time system to a continuous-time system. Then using the results for continuous-time systems you can conclude results for the discrete time system. Chapter 6 has results for two-time scale systems.

If you know any other books/papers that have useful results not covered by these references I would like to add them to the collection.

Comment: There is also this interesting article for singular perturbation analysis in discrete-time systems: [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0016003296000762)